# How to Handle return session in load balancing

Tags: linux, apache, load-balancing, round-robin

I have following network scnerio, i have LB-> proxy -> LB -> Web server - > LB -> App server.

Load balancer is working in Round Robin fashion. Now how can i grantee that applications handling return session. Load balancer automatically handle  return session or we need to configure anywhere in settings.

[image: Load balance return session]

Answer (score 0):

What you have described (and illustrated in your deployment diagram) seems overly complicated, but I will not pretend to know your ultimate use-case for this implementation. Also, you did not mention what you are currently using for the Load Balancer (HAproxy, Amazon ELB, F5, etc) but I would look into configuring "sticky sessions" on the load balancer. Sticky sessions will ensure that particular clients with a specific session are balanced/routed to the proper application server. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what you described you need session persistence. You can get session persistence from several different options all depending upon your type of load balancer. For example, I use F5's Big-IP LTM and for session persistence I can choose from SSL, source address, destination address, cookies, etc. to create a sticky session. In session persistence the user's client will allows go to the server that the client was directed to in the beginning.